# Date encoding MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, date, encoding

I've got a database and I want to get the date field. The problem is that this field is encoding with a system I haven't seen before.

Dates are saved like this: B50424 which correspond with 24.04.2015. Is not a coincidence because another date field is saved like: B50520 And correspond with 20.05.2015.

So as we can see the dates are reversed, except with the last character. Is a B and I don't know what it means. I don't have access to the webapp, I just have got the database and I would like to know if this is a system encoding or not. 
Any Idea?

Comment: Speculation:  The data designer may have chosen a non-standard shortcut for dates like B5 represents 2015?

Comment: Yeah, it might be possible to fix using SQL.  But I would do it in PHP/Perl/Java/whatever.